# Does assistance damage count towards completing personal mission StuG-IV HT-15?

Tags: world-of-tanks

In the first set of personal missions, Heavy Tank #15 lists primary condition:

> Damage caused, damage received, and damage blocked by armor must total at least 6,000 HP.

Does assistance damage also count toward this total?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not. In all of these missions it is explicitly stated if assisted damage counts. Most notably in the Platoon missions it counts and in scout missions but not in the HT ones.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it does.  When assistance damage counts, it's pretty clearly stated in the description. If it doesn't say it in the description, it doesn't count.

Comment: how is it made clear? Could you expand on this at all?

Comment: Ah, the smart guy with unlimited time arrived here as well.....